# Is there an equivalent term in the lagrangian of classical newtonian physics to the corresponding $\frac{1}{2}m^2\phi^2$ term of QFT?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, field-theory, classical-field-theory

In classical field theory and quantum field theory, the lagrangian could have a mass term in the form: $\frac{1}{2}m^2\phi^2$.

Is there an equivalent term in the lagrangian of classical newtonian physics ? (no field theory)
If not, why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest analogue of the quadratic potential density ${\cal V}(\phi)=\frac{1}{2}m^2\phi^2$ in field theory is the harmonic quadratic potential $V(q)=\frac{1}{2}kq^2$ in point mechanics.

It should be stressed that the notion of mass enters very differently in field theory and in point mechanics, see e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/278785/2451) Phys.SE post.

Comment: Thanks a lot for explanation